# CSV file to JSON for nested array generic template using python (for csv to mongodb insert)

Tags: python, json, mongodb, csv

I want to create the JSON file from CSV file using the generic python script.

Found hone package from GitHub but some of the functionalities missing in that code.

[csv to json](https://github.com/chamkank/hone)

I want to code like generic template CSV to JSON.

```
[
{
"birth": {
  "day": "7",
  "month": "May",
  "year": "1985"
},
"name": "Bob",
"reference": "TRUE",
"reference name": "Smith"
}
]
```

Only handled above type of JSON only.

```
 [
{
 "Type": "AwsEc2Instance",
"Id": "i-cafebabe",
"Partition": "aws",
"Region": "us-west-2",
"Tags": {
"billingCode": "Lotus-1-2-3",
"needsPatching": "true"
 },
 "Details": {
"AwsEc2Instance": {
"Type": "i3.xlarge",
"ImageId": "ami-abcd1234",
"IpV4Addresses": [ "54.194.252.215", "192.168.1.88" ],
"IpV6Addresses": [ "2001:db812341a2b::123" ],
"KeyName": "my_keypair",
"VpcId": "vpc-11112222",
"SubnetId": "subnet-56f5f633",
"LaunchedAt": "2018-05-08T16:46:19.000Z"
 }
 }
 }
 ]
```

I want to handle nested array[] ,{}

Comment: What is your question, what missing in this package?

Comment: I updated the question now its understandable. Issues mentioned in the Github.       
                                                              https://github.com/chamkank/hone/issues/5

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this before and below code can be modified as I have not seen your dataset.

```
   dataframe = pd.read_excel('dataframefilepath', encoding='utf-8', header=0)
   '''Adding to list to finally save it as JSON'''
    df = []
    for (columnName, columnData) in dataframe.iteritems():
        if dataframe.columns.get_loc(columnName) > 0:
            for indata, rwdata in dataframe.iterrows():
                for insav, rwsave  in df_to_Save.iterrows():
                    if rwdata.Selected_Prediction == rwsave.Selected_Prediction:

                        #print()
                        df_to_Save.loc[insav, 'Value_to_Save'] = rwdata[dataframe.columns.get_loc(columnName)]
                        #print(rwdata[dataframe.columns.get_loc(columnName)])
            df.append(df_to_Save.set_index('Selected_Prediction').T.to_dict('record'))

    df = eval(df)

    '''Saving in JSON format'''
    path_to_save = '\\your path'
    with open(path_to_save, 'w') as json_file:
       json.dump(df, json_file)
```